# What is a constituency in the Georgian political system?

Tags: election, parliament, political-system, europe, republic-of-georgia

I want to try alternative voting systems and wanted to take Georgia as my mock example as their political elections data is very granular as one can see [here](https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/46/shape/89486/shape_type/1?data_type=official). Georgian has a unicameral parliament, currently consisting of 150 members; of these, 77 are proportional representatives and **73 are elected through single-member district plurality system, representing their constituencies**.

**What is a constituency in the Georgian political system? Is it a district?** A precinct? I would guess it is a district.

It is a single-member district plurality system. According [to the Wikipedia article for the next parliamentary elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_Georgian_parliamentary_election), it uses a modified two-round system, in which candidates must receive over 50% of the valid vote to win in the first round. A second round is held between the top two candidates if there is no winner in the first round.

However, the results for a given precinct on the official [data elections website](https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/46/shape/89498/shape_type/3?data_type=official&change_shape_type=true&parent_shape_clickable=false) show the results of all parties. Are these the results of the first round only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately political terms are not universal in English, and a translation that makes sense in one dialect can be meaningless in another. Constituency is commonly used in Commonwealth English for the political unit from which winners are elected. Wikipedia gives a large number of alternative names [on this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_district), where it identifies it with the term "electoral district".

Based on [this](https://www.constituteproject.org/constitution/Georgia_2013.pdf?lang=en) English language version of the Georgian Constitution as of 2013, it appear that

> **Article 105, paragraph 4**
>
> A  candidate  having  obtained  the  most  number  of  votes  but  not  less  than  onethird of votes shall be deemed elected in a majoritarian electoral district.

Hence I suspect no run-offs occurred during the 2016 election.